# How can I install a switch to power a bathroom TV off safely and discreetly?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch, waterproofing, television

Firstly, I'll start by saying that I have no electrical skills apart from basic changing a socket skills...

I have a small bathroom that I've decided to put a waterproof TV in. The TV is going to go in the centre of a stud frame attached to a brick wall. The wall has been boarded and will eventually be tiled. This is at the end of the bathroom, opposite the bath and sink with the wires already having been embedded behind the boarded stud frame.

The plan is to put the power adaptor for the TV in the loft above, running from a power outlet that I had wired up there, as I wanted to have the ability to switch the power to the TV on and off, so that the TV isn't left constantly receiving power fed into it (to avoid the possibly of heating it up and being damaged after a few years). I'm planning to put some kind of switch to the right of the TV, that would allow me to do this. My brother reckons this would be ok and so under his instruction, I've placed 2 2.5 T&E cables running behind the stud frame, that reach between where we intend to put the switch and the power socket in the loft. The plan is to insert the extra link of a switched fused spur (3A) between the loft power outlet to the TV power adaptor and place this switched fused spur in the bathroom, inserted flush in the tile wall.

As far as I can see by the diagrams I've looked at, the TV is going to be in the Outside Zone (not zones, 0, 1 or 2) so I could probably use a normal (non IP rated) switch but I would ideally like to use a waterproof switch, to prevent any chance of anyone with wet hands getting more than they bargained for when all they want to watch is Corrie!

I've considered using a PIR but didn't want to go this route as my Mrs will use the bath and possibly not move much whilst watching TV, so I don't want her to splash about to get the thing to come back on again. I've looked around on the net and the only waterproof switches I've see are for external use and look quite tough... I'd be happy with a small switch if possible. I've seen options like these:

A sensor switch that sits behind a wall and you just hold your hand near the tile to switch on or off - looked a bit pricey but I don't know what I'd need to incorporate this: http://www.sensor.co.uk/switches/bathroom_switch/

The Aquadesign and System Design IP 44 switches by Merten that are waterproof light switches - I can't see them anywhere to actually buy

The Clipsal switch - again, can't see this to buy anywhere apart from in Australia

The questions I have are:
Is the use of a switched fused spur safe to do like this?
Do I need (is it best) to use a switched fuse spur or is there some other way to go about this?
Would a simple cover to go over a normal switch suffice, such as this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bathroom-Switch-Protector-Plastic-Waterproof/dp/B007VCTMS6?

To give a clearer idea of the environment, I've attached a photo so you can see where this is currently up to...

[image: photo of the bathroom TV wall]

The tile wall will be finished in the same red tiles that are at the bottom and as there is white in the room, I'd like the switch to be discreet if possible to fit the room as it stands i.e. no industrial grey external switches.

Any suggestions, answers, etc will be gratefully received. Please feel free to ask me anything else if what I've written isn't clear.

Thanks in advance.

Del

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's been ages since this question was first asked and I've only just managed to get round to wiring this up. I went for an [infra-red motion sensor switch](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Leyton-Lighting-Switching-Kitchen-Cabinet/dp/B0060HG9HU%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduc08-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB0060HG9HU). This has been placed up in the loft, with the motion sensor placed discretely under the frame in which the TV sits, so that it is out of sight. The actual switch unit is in the loft space and is wired such that when activated, the power to the TV DC adaptor is powered on and the TV then comes on. It works really well, with the TV not just going into standby mode when the sensor detects motion, but coming on fully. The only thing left for me to do really is add an additional speaker in the ceiling, which I'll do in due course as the built in speakers in the TV are very tinny, but for now, this is complete.

Here is a photo of the wall with the TV on:

[image]

Thanks for your answers and in particular, the answer by @Hightower proved to be the most useful as it reminded me of the setup I have in my other bathroom on my cabinet, that illuminated with LED lights, as the swipe of hand over the sensor at the side of it.

Answer (score 3):

You could go the route of having no switches in the bathroom, and only a plug and switch upstairs Loft.

Step 1: Get a standby plug adapter, which will shut off power to the TV when its in standby mode. this will reduce electrical risk, fire and save power. - the unit has an infra-red reset switch, so when it senses your remote IR beam, it will energise the TV up again.

That way, all you need to do, is turn the TV off when you are done. and don't think about it anymore.

Step 2:
You can actually look at the new Samsung Smart TV's with motion sensor on/off switches.  all you need to do is wave your hand near the Samsung logo and the TV Will switch on/off...

Answer (score 1):

I am also remodeling our bathroom and have placed the on/off switch next to the light switch which is outside the bathroom door as you enter. I guess the other way would be to use a normal corded isolation switch mounted on the ceiling. 
Good luck
( I am also not a qualified electrician but do have a friendly one who checks what is done and would recommend same. )